# Unable to login to RStudio Server after changing user id in Ubuntu? RStudio Initialization Error - Error occured during transmission

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, rstudio-server, userid

I'm unable to login to my RStudio Server installed on a ubuntu container. I've created the accounts and changed the user ids.

Screenshot of error:

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `/var/log/syslog` there are Operation not Permitted errors on temporary files under `/tmp/rstudio-rsessions` - I just had to change the ownership or delete the files user-d and user-d.pid.

Comment: For RStudio Server Verion 1.4.1717 I found these in `/var/run/rstudio-server/rstudio-rsession/` and the logs to find them were retrieved by running `journalctl`.